# How to export an interface from a single vue component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

export interface OChannelsFilterFormForm {
    filterBy: {
      youCreated: boolean,
      youCanAddTo: boolean,
      hideType: string
    },
    sortBy: string
  }

@Component({
  components: {
    AButtonSubmit,
    ValidationObserver
  }
})
export default class OChannelsFilterForm extends Vue {
  form: any = {
    filterBy: {
      youCreated: false,
      youCanAddTo: false,
      hideType: 'none'
    },
    sortBy: 'aToZ'
  };

  submit () {
    this.$emit('child-output', this.form);
    this.$emit('close');
  }
}
</script>
```

All fine, import the interface into another vue component and the ide does not complain.

But as soon as I build, typescript says he interface cannot be found :/

Is there a way to export interfaces from a single vue component and import into another?

Comment: This depends on the implementation of IDE, etc. Don't use named exports in SFC for reusable things, keep them separately.

Comment: Could you please provide an example how you `import` both the interface and component class from within another file?

Comment: sure will extend the OP

Comment: ahhh man.. thanks for the hint :D

The component including the file needed the .vue extension added

Comment: is there a way to get typescript to be able to import a .vue without having to type a .vue.. or as @EstusFlask you mentioned configure the IDE - I am using phpstorm, is there a way to get it to auto include the .vue file ext?

Comment: nevermind - I updated a few packages and it just started working :p

Comment: Importing an interface from 1 .vue file into another works - but importing an interface from vue to ts file interface  does not

Comment: This is not about TS itself but things with unspecified behaviour, which .vue loader and IDEs are. Even if it works in one IDE, it may break in another. It's known that named exports don't always work as expected with them. Just don't do this to not end up yourself cornered when one of these things breaks. A reusable interface isn't a part of a component, therefore it deserves to be defined in separate .ts

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simple - add the .vue extension when importing.

Comment: FWIW, .vue extension is really necessary in TS imports. There are tools that don't like this though.